# Manipulating repositories for specific Monticello packages programatically?

Tags: version-control, smalltalk, pharo, monticello

I want to automate some Monticello tasks. For this purpose i would have to first choose certain Monticello packages and then i would like to be able to:

- add repositories,
- remove repositories,
- add user and password information for certain (Smalltalkhub) repositories.

I saw there is a small paragraph on "Programmatically adding repositories" in the upcoming [Monticello chapter](http://pharobooks.gforge.inria.fr/PharoByExampleTwo-Eng/latest/Monticello.pdf) of "Deep into Pharo".

Can [Gofer](http://pharobooks.gforge.inria.fr/PharoByExampleTwo-Eng/latest/Gofer.pdf) be used to automate tasks like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least I found an answer to my third question:

> How to programatically add user and password information for certain
>   (Smalltalkhub) repositories.

```
(MCRepositoryGroup default repositories
    select: [:each | (each isKindOf: MCHttpRepository)
        and: [each locationWithTrailingSlash includesSubstring: 'http://smalltalkhub.com/mc/MyName/']])
    do: [:each | each user: 'MyName'; password: 'MyPassword'].
```

The credit goes to ["Pharo: Tips and Tricks" by Mariano Martinez Peck](http://marianopeck.wordpress.com/2012/05/19/pharo-tips-and-tricks/)

Answer (score 1):

Gofer is supposed to be used to programmatically do what you do by hand with the Monticello UI. If you find things missing, please discuss them on the mailing lists.